# How to correctly pass a PHP variable to another PHP page?

Tags: php, android, sql, eclipse

I have an android app where it uploads the file along with other variables using PHP to a server. I want to insert the uploaded file name(from the PHP file) to the PHP file which handles the inserting of variables to the database.

I want to get file_path to the another php file.
UploadToServer.php

```
<?php
session_start();

   $file_path = "uploads/";

   $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
   $_SESSION['image'] = "$file_path";
       echo "success";
   } else{
       echo "fail";
   }

?>
```

create_product.php

```
<?php
session_start();
/*
 * Following code will create a new report row
 * All report details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();
$image = $_SESSION['image'];

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['description']) && isset($_POST['type'])) {

    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO reports(type, name, location, description, image) VALUES('$type', '$name', '$location', '$description', '$file_path')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "report successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Please tell me what's wrong.

Comment: $_SESSION['image'] = $file_path; this will store the data in the session. That said it doesn't do anything?

Comment: On a sidenote, stop using mysql functions and start learning and using PDO or Mysqli prepared statements. Mysql is officially Deprecated

Comment: Please explain better what you want as all is pretty unclear to me. For instance which php script is calling the other? And what exactly do you wantbto transfer? At the moment the subject and your description do not match for me.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated, not Mysql. Just don't want anyone to get confused and think the server itself is deprecated. :)

Comment: Why would your Android app call two different php pages for one operation? I think you need to rethink that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no session involved at all, you need to combine the 2 scripts:

```
<?php
// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['description']) && isset($_POST['type'])) {

    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success save to db";
        $type = $_POST['type'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $location = $_POST['location'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];

        // include db connect class
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

        // connecting to db
        $db = new DB_CONNECT();

        // mysql inserting a new row
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO reports(type, name, location, description, image) 
                               VALUES('$type', '$name', '$location', '$description', '$file_path')");

        // check if row inserted or not
        if ($result) {
            // successfully inserted into database
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "report successfully created.";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // failed to insert row
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else{
       echo "fail to upload will not save to DB";
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Please note:

- This code will insert the record in the database only, it it
  successfully uploaded the file.
- mysql is deprecated
- use mysqli or PDO, and prepare query to avoid SQL injection